# Choosing a Ninject module using configuration file

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I am new to dependency injection frameworks and Ninject, but I am trying to choose which classes I inject into my project based on my config file.  I figured the best way to do this would be with their modules feature.  If I used my debug config, I could use a module designed with debug classes.  If I used my production config, I could use a module designed with production classes.  What would be the best way of declaring which module to use in my configuration files?

Comment: What do you mean by "debug config" and "production config"? How do you determine or specify which it is?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit The configuration file that I use with each specific scenario.  The only thing that would ideally change from a debug environment to a production environment would be the configuration file.

Comment: There's no specific Ninject functionality to determine which modules to load dependent on a config file. However, reading config files is a topic with a lot of Q/A on SO as well as articles on the internet, so i don't think it's worth to post an answer as basically you should be able to find a solution in the existing material.